# off php engine and htaccess using regex in apache

Tags: apache-2.2, php, .htaccess

I have some sites on a server. they all have a drectory named 'image-upload' where users of sites upload their images.

I want to:

- Off PHP engine for this directory on all the sites
- disable .htaccess on this directory on all the sites

Can I do it apache config file using regex?

Comment: what is the reason of giving negative point to my question?

Answer (score 0):

You can set configuration options using a FilesMatch and DirectoryMatch directove which uses a globbing patter (not a regex). But you don't even need a glob: just using a Directory directive has the same effect.

[The manual describes](http://php.net/manual/en/apache.configuration.php) doing this via .htacess, in your httpd.conf....

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/image-upload">
   php_flag engine off
   AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

(but adding a .htaccess file to disable the engine as well would be a good idea).

It would be a better idea to keep user uploads completely outside the document root and mediate all access via a proxy script.